# Placing a timestamp on a cell accross multiple sheets on edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I tried many different variations of this script and can't figure out why it's not working.
I want to update the same cell  "J3" with a timestamp across multiple tabs onedit. I have another function on the spreadsheet already using onEdit(e), so i set a new function with an onEdit trigger.
I retrieve the names of the tabs I want to update and store them in an array.

```
function Overview_timestamp(e) //function to use in the onEdit trigger
{
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var range = e.range;
  var cellToStamp = "J3" ;
  var name_range =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Structure').getRange(2, 5, 14, 1).getValues(); //sheets i want to update
var flattened_name_range = [] ; //converting into 1D array
for (var i = 0; i < name_range.length; i++) {
    flattened_name_range.push(name_range[i][0]);
}


   if(flattened_name_range.indexOf(activeSheet())!==-1 ) {

      activeSheet.getRange(cellToStamp).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");}
}
```

Comment: Each function in a project must have a unique name.  So I recommend that you combine your onEdit()s

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 function Overview_timestamp(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet name') {//just to limit action to one sheet but it would be nice to have additional control like clicking a  checkbox or selecting a value on a validated cell.
    const shts = e.source.getSheetByName('Structure').getRange(2, 5, 14).getValues().flat();
    shts.forEach(n => {
      e.source.getSheetByName(n).getRange('J3').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    });
  }
}
```

I did it this way on my sheet using a checkbox at A1 on Sheet1

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==1 && e.value=='TRUE') {
    //e.source.toast('cond');
    const shts = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(2, 5, 14).getValues().flat().filter(e=>e);
    shts.forEach(n => {
      e.source.getSheetByName(n).getRange('J3').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    });
    e.range.setValue('FALSE');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But it did not work. 
It had it working actually and changed something and now it stopped working.

Comment: thanks again, Tried your code and did not work for me. Even tried it inside the already existing onEdit.